# Change Page's <title> Tag Using functions.php File

Tags: plugins, filters, api, wp-head

In my child theme's functions.php file, I'm trying to change a page's title tag:

```
function custom_title() {
    return "Page Title";
}
add_filter( 'wp_head', 'custom_title', 9999 );
```

The code above is not changing the page's default title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're looking for the `wp_title` filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) out

```
function custom_title($title_parts) {
    $title_parts['title'] = "Page Title";
    return $title_parts;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'custom_title' );
```

In `custom_title`, `$title_parts` contains 'title', 'page' (the pagination), 'tagline' (the slogan you specified) and 'site'. Set "title" the way you like.

Comment: Thank you! This did what I wanted to do, NOT wp_head().

Comment: Add `$title_parts['tagline'] = "";` if you don't want a tagline in the title.